# Jquery DatePicker Tooltip Format

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

This is my query i need the tooltip for all the days eg: when mouse over moves to the sep/27/2011. tooltip should  display should show as "Tuesday,September 27,2011". How to do implement this?.This  is my jquery datepicker

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
        $( "#<%= this.txtFrom.ClientID %>" ).datepicker({
            showOn: 'both',
            buttonImage: "Images/calendar.gif",
            buttonImageOnly: true,
            showmonth:true,
            autoSize: true,
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            showAnim: 'slideDown',
            buttonText: "",
            duration: 'fast',
           showOtherMonths: true,
           selectOtherMonths: true
                });
        $(".ui-datepicker-trigger").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');
});
    });
</script
```

>

Finally i found the solution:

```
          beforeShowDay: function(date) { return [true, '', $.datepicker.formatDate('DD, MM d, yy', date)]; },
```

Then 
//otheroptions

Comment: have u read the documentation here http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Tooltip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think you will need to have it on onSelect method:

```
$( "#<%= this.txtFrom.ClientID %>" ).datepicker({ 
    showOn: 'both',
    buttonImage: "Images/calendar.gif",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    showmonth:true,
    autoSize: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showAnim: 'slideDown',
    buttonText: "",
    duration: 'fast',
    showOtherMonths: true,
    selectOtherMonths: true,
    // all your other options above.
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        var d = new Date(inst.selectedYear, inst.selectedMonth, inst.selectedDay),
            format = $.datepicker.formatDate( 'DD, d MM, yy', d ) 
        this.alt = format; //You may want to use title instead of alt, depending on what element you are using.
    }
});
```

Im using the `alt` text in this example to give you the format on the input

live example: http://jsbin.com/eliwut/

Comment: Can you edit it in my code i have used your coding it is not working..i think i have done some mistakes in the closing and opening brackets.i am using 2005 so i cant find out the exact closing parenthisis

Comment: No it is not working i have used this code...    showOtherMonths: true,
           selectOtherMonths: true
       onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
         var d = new Date(inst.selectedYear, inst.selectedMonth, inst.selectedDay),
        format = $.datepicker.formatDate( 'DD, d MM, yy', d ) 
          this.alt = format;
           });
    $(".ui-datepicker-trigger").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
$( "#<%= this.txtFrom.ClientID %>" ).datepicker({
showOn: 'both',buttonImage: "Images/calendar.gif",buttonImageOnly:true,showmonth:true,
autoSize: true,changeMonth: true,
changeYear: true,
buttonText: "",
showOtherMonths: true,
selectOtherMonths: true
onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
var d = new Date(inst.selectedYear, inst.selectedMonth,inst.selectedDay),format $.datepicker.formatDate( 'DD, d MM, yy', d ) this.alt = format;});$(".ui-datepicker-trigger").mouseover(function() {$(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');}});});</script>

Comment: you only need to add onSelect into your options on your datepicker, just copy the onSelect and paste it inside your option object, have updated my example.

Comment: Hi I found the solution                   beforeShowDay: function(date) { return [true, '', $.datepicker.formatDate('DD, MM d, yy', date)]; },

Comment: Okey, then I misunderstood your question, I thought you wanted a tooltip on the input after you selected a date.